# Android: how to use Sugar database library or another library to read copied database from assets and make queries on it?

Tags: android, sqlite, sugarorm

i succeeded to copy database from the assets folder to android sqlite database but i want to use 3rd library to query this database instead of the native query builder. i searched ,i find a lot of libraries but these library treat only with the database created by them not the copied database from the assets

i find this question  how to use Sugar library [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225541/android-sugar-orm-with-existing-db-custom-file-path)

but i did not help me yet.

Comment: Usually you have to copy the database file from asset to the app-private data directory and then you can open it as a regular database using it's file-path.

Comment: OK i did it and i could make query using the SQLiteDatabase successfully. but how to refer to any 3rd library to read from my copied database not to the database created by this library @Robert

Comment: Sorry, but this is library specific - there is no general way. Please update your question and say exactly what library you are talking about.

Comment: @MinaFarid, can you show me code where you copy the database file from assets folder and create database from it ? i am in similar situation. I used this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30419721/7576112) but when i query the database i realize that no new record is created which means the database is not imported from file.